# Using gulp to combine and edit multiple json files into one

Tags: json, gulp

I'm a little bit into gulp and I'm looking for the right combination of tasks to read n amount of similarly formatted json files, pull out a specific array from each, combine them, and save as a new file. I've successfully used gulp-concat to combine files, and gulp-json-editor to change values on one file, but I'm having a hard time wrapping my head around how to string the processes together.

n number of json files formatted as follows:

```
{
    "id": "groupofthings1",
    "things": [
        { ... },
        { ... },
    ],
    ...
}
```

Desired single file output containing all "things":

```
[
    { ... },
    { ... },
    { ... },
    { ... },
    ...
]
```

Comment: Build an array with each entry representing one of the files as a string, then merge the result with something like `'{' + json_array.join(',') + '}'` Or, you could just load/parse all the JSON files, merge the objects then write the resulting object back out as JSON.

Comment: @joemaller - But how do I do that with gulp plugins? I'm confident I can build the data structure if I can get the right streams in the right places with the right plugins.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Took me a bit of searching, but ended up finding [jsoncombine](https://www.npmjs.org/package/gulp-jsoncombine)

It loads all json files and runs them through a custom function as a hash of json objects. Each json object is saved under its original files name.

```
gulp.src("./groups/of/things/**/things.json")
.pipe(jsoncombine("all-things.json",function(data){
    // do any work on data here
    return new Buffer(JSON.stringify(data));
 }))
 .pipe(gulp.dest("./dest"));
```

Comment: but if i want to merge just 2 files within a directory? for example i have folder to hold all config files, one of the it's base file and others are env based files, sometimes i want to merge dev+base, sometimes prod+base and so on. any chance to do it with this package?

Comment: @ShlomiSasson you can pass in an array of specific file names/patterns. E.g., `gulp.src(['./file1.json', './base.json'])`